# PhoneGap jQuery Mobile

Tags: xcode, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to make a PhoneGap app using jquerymobile, but it doesn't seem to work...

In my index.html I wrote below code;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

I put jquery mobile files into my www file.

Could someone teach me how to read jquery file using PhoneGap??

I'm sorry for my English is not good...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have some sample applications in github repository which you can use for reference.

[cordova-examples](https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples)

[phonegap with jquery mobile](https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/ios-cordova-video)

Comment: Thank you! this helped me. Actually, what I did to solve my problem is that I deleted js files and put directly into my www folder!